# simple questions simple answers

Tags: discussion

I'have to admit that I have still a problem to vote up simple elementary questions and also simple answers that could be solved by looking up any site for music theory or searching at google. I understand that an beginner of music has problems to formulate the question and knowing how to ask is actually their problem.

Should I vote considering that other beginners will look up in SE instead in music theory having -  the same or similar questions - or should I vote down to "punish" OP for not looking up before elsewhere?

Or should  I rather ignore elemenatry questions - like quetions asking for advices in equipment.

Comment: Surprisingly, vote (or not to vote) whatever you feel the best, either for you personally or for the best of this site's curation. The tooltip for up/downvoting can help as a guideline: **shows research effort; useful and clear**.

Answer (score 2):

**I'm a believer in the idea that the complexity of the question should not solely determine its merit.** Sure, no one likes "what key signature is this" questions, but I've seen a lot of good questions on the basic level, like [this one](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/67209/45266), and many others. Personally, I upvote beginner questions all the time, provided they aren't duplicates (and I check pretty religiously) or otherwise worthy of closure.

*Actually, your question might be somewhat of a duplicate of [this](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2899/45266), but if not, you should probably read it anyway.*

And as others have said, vote any way you choose. See Andrew T's comment on the question for an explanation.

Comment: Actually, there was a question just the other day that really made me think that someone was testing how desperate we were for questions and whether we would answer anything. It showed a score and asked "What is this hash tag note? I know it's a black key but I forgot which". (And yes, we answered it.)

Comment: I remember that one. A couple minutes ago, https://music.stackexchange.com/q/82777/45266 popped up in the review queues.

Comment: Note that, "What key signature is this?" is explicitly off-topic, and "what is a key signature?" is a completely appropriate question.